# Area of 2-dimensional surface

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, surfaces

I want to  calculate the area of $$M = \left \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : 1-z^2 = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}, -1 \leq z \leq 1\right \}.$$
First parametrize $M$ a.e. via $$\Phi : ]-1, 1[ \times ]0, 2\pi[ \to M, \\
(z,t) \mapsto ((1-z^2) \cos t, (1-z^2) \sin t, z)$$
and we get 
$$A = 2\pi\int _{-1}^1 (1-z^2)\sqrt{1+4z^2}dz = 2\pi \int_{\text{arsinh(-2)}}^{\text{arsinh(2)}}(1-4\sinh(x))\cosh^2(x)dx$$
Now is this the correct way so far and how to proceed?

Comment: If I am correct with what you mean by $dS$ then I did that and this is what I got.

Comment: Indeed, it is, I just wasn't following your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work looks correct (I had to do the parametrization...but I didn't check the last substitution fully), and the last integral doesn't look so terrible. First:

$$\int\cosh^2x\,dx=\frac14\int\left(e^{2x}+e^{-2x}+2\right)dx=\frac18\left(e^{2x}-e^{-2x}+4x\right)+C$$

and

$$\int\sinh x\cosh^2x\,dx=\frac13\cosh^3x+C$$

Finally, remember that

$$\text{arcsinh}\,x=\log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)\;,\;\;\cosh(\text{arcsinh}\,x)=\sqrt{x^2+1}$$

Comment: Thanks, with these terrible looking integrals I am sometimes unsure if what I have done is correct. BTW: the inverse of the hyperbolic functions are called arsinh, arcos (because they measure area enclosed by the hyperbola and two rays from the origin).

Comment: @Staki42 In fact, they appear in many forms: as $\;\sinh^{-1}\;$ and etc. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo52z.jpg), or as you say $\;\text{arshinh}\,x\;$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions), and also as $\;\text{argsinh}\,x\;$ and etc. (http://home.scarlet.be/math/hyp.htm#Inverse-hyperbolic-f) . The most usual, though, seems to be the first one mentioned above.

Comment: Interesting! I only remember I was told to not write $\text{arcsinh}$ since it's not the arc length being measured :)

Comment: @Staki42 Whoever told you may have been a zealot of little points. Nobody will ever put in doubt what that means (as far as they know what hyperbolic functions are...). If that were a good reason, why then take the name hyperbolic **sine, cosine** and etc. if those are **not** trigonometric functions? Well, we want to stress the similarities between both kinds of functions. Mind you, I agree with the notation arsinh$\,(x)\;$ more...but I really don't pay that much attention to those little details

Comment: thanks for your opinion, good point that they aren't actually trigonometric functions!